# How to start OpenLink Virtuoso on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, putty, virtuoso

I have a remote server with Ubuntu OS. I am using `putty` to run commands on server. I installed OpenLink open source Virtuoso on it.

Now when I start the server using following commands:

> To start the server you have two steps
>
> 1. Go to `cd  /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db`
> 2. then type `/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t -f &`

The server starts successfully and I am able to access conductor and stuff, but as soon as I close my `putty` session, the Virtuoso server also shuts down. I am also running `tomcat` and `LAMP` on that machine.  Those two still keep on running but strangely Virtuoso shuts down.

How can I make stay running even when i disconnect from my `putty` session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-f` argument makes the Virtuoso instance run in the `+foreground` even though the process has been put in the background (by the trailing ampersand, `&`), and it is tied to your login session.

You can get similar output effects, without the binding to your login session, with the `-d` or `+debug` argument.

You can also start the instance without the stdout feedback, with the `+loglevel` as set in the `virtuoso.ini` file (default `loglevel` is `5`), by leaving off both `-d` and `-f` arguments.

So the two commands to execute become:

> 1. `cd /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db`
> 2. `/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/virtuoso-t`

Now, that `db` directory is not where I'd expect to find it, so the guide you're following may need some additional correction.  You may find (my employer) [OpenLink Software's guide](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSUbuntuNotes) more helpful.

For future reference, OpenLink Software has several paths to support, with Virtuoso and otherwise, such as the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://bit.ly/au3EMD), or our [Support site](http://support.openlinksw.com/), or our own [Support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/), or the IRC channel `#openlink-virtuoso` on Freenode (`irc://chat.freenode.net/#openlink-virtuoso`).